# Where do I call PHP in wordpress to use the loop?

Tags: wordpress

I am attempting to call a javascript function that creates an in page popup that displays all post content on the wordpress site.  I think I can figure out how to include JS into my page from the wp-admin dashboard.  I have read a lot about 'The Loop' which seems to be what I want - post content with out any formatting.  I think I have the code that I want to use.

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

 <div class="entry">
   <?php the_content(); ?>
 </div>

 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

However, I have no idea where to put this code.  I have tried inserting it directly into the admin dashboard, but to no avail.  I have tried creating a custom template through the [Exposito](http://wpshower.com/themes/expositio/) theme but it always ends up with the blank white page (I think because the theme isnt easily templated).  In short, my question is where should I put the php code to call up my loop?

Comment: That's the Loop but you have to make a query first to fetch the posts, usually by category, author, most recent, etc. Check [this link](http://www.google.com.co/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcodex.wordpress.org%2FClass_Reference%2FWP_Query&ei=gNLkULvCDJG08ATY4oHwDw&usg=AFQjCNFjSQ_s-LVXT7_Syz2PSYsZbpeVgg&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.eWU)

Comment: [***The Codex is your friend***](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page#Learn_How_to_Use_WordPress).

Comment: @b__ - That is one great link :-)